# What different versions of xbox 360 are there? What is the hd for with xbox?

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XBox 360 versions and differences between them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343/xbox-360-versions-and-differences-between-them)

What are the different versions of xbox 360?

What exactly is the hard drive used for, I see 4GB and up to 250GB.  It can't be just for saving games now can it?

Comment: duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/343/8366; it'd be easy enough to add hard drive information to one or more answers there if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major families of Xbox 360:

Xbox 360 "Classic" - Comes in 0GB ("Core") 0.25GB ("Arcade"), 0.5GB ("Arcade"), 20GB, 60GB, 120GB ("Elite"), and 250GB (also "Elite") models.

Xbox 360 S (smaller, has a special power port for the Kinect, has built-in Wi-Fi) - Comes in 4GB, 250GB, and 320GB (Special Edition only) models.

The two families use different hard drive bays, so drives for one family of systems do not work in the other.  All consoles that you can buy new are Slim models.

The Hard Drive has two main uses other than for saved games:

1. Some games give you an install option, which improves load times.
2. You can purchase downloadable games from the Xbox Live Marketplace.